# Matching any character in regex

Tags: regex, utf-8

I have a 'utf-8' string which is usually like this

'\x99\xb3...' and so on.

However, there might be malformed bytes like '\x\y' and so on.

I have tried using regex expression like '\.\' but it doesnt seem to work. How do i remove such malformed bytes in my utf8 string?

Comment: What programming language or text editor are you using for this? Different regex implementations have different features.

Comment: @KennethK. I am using python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a couple of things going on here. I'm using Kerwin's example of a guess at your input -- but dropping the double-backslashes because I don't infer that's what you'll be working with: `\x99\xb3\x\y\x99\x\xb3`

1. To start, you didn't escape your backslashes, so you were essentially telling the regex engine that you wanted to match a literal period (`.`), followed by another literal that you didn't provide.
2. Second, I don't think you need to match (and thus remove from further analysis) the closing backslash; rather, I think you need to put that portion of your search in a lookeahead group.

See if this gives you the results you expect: `(\\.)(?=\\)`

You can see (and tinker with) it online at https://regex101.com/r/eB8mH1/1.

Answer (score 1):

guess your input is `\x99\xb3\\x\\y\x99\\x\xb3`,then remove all `\x\y`

```
  import re
  p = re.compile(r'\\[a-z](?!\w)')
  test_str = "\x99\xb3\\x\\y\x99\\x\xb3"
  result = re.sub(p, "",test_str)
  print test_str
  print result
```